# Can't change size of svg logo

Tags: css, svg, tailwind-css

I created a svg component using the svgr playground.

```
const Logo = (props) => (
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" {...props}>
    <path d="M5.857 18.708c1.638 0 2.995-.36 4.07-1.08 1.075-.721 1.613-1.769 1.613-3.144-.083-1.855-1.464-3.246-4.144-4.173l-1.44-.597c-.314-.1-.538-.198-.67-.298a.45.45 0 0 1-.198-.373c0-.414.273-.62.819-.62.678 0 1.182.347 1.513 1.043l3.698-1.044c-.893-2.22-2.614-3.329-5.162-3.329-1.522 0-2.788.398-3.797 1.193C1.15 7.08.645 8.116.645 9.39c0 .398.058.766.174 1.106.116.34.29.638.521.894.232.257.455.48.67.671.215.19.488.369.82.534.33.166.582.286.756.36.174.075.41.162.707.261l.422.15 1.49.546c.363.133.6.244.707.335a.449.449 0 0 1 .16.36c0 .431-.404.647-1.215.647-1.191 0-1.903-.53-2.134-1.59L0 14.509c.463 2.8 2.416 4.2 5.857 4.2zm11.636 0c1.638 0 2.845-.63 3.623-1.888v1.615h5.112V5.366h-5.112v7.156c0 1.474-.505 2.21-1.514 2.21-1.026 0-1.539-.736-1.539-2.21V5.366h-5.112v7.653c0 3.793 1.514 5.69 4.542 5.69zm16.103-.273V11.28c0-1.475.504-2.212 1.513-2.212 1.026 0 1.54.737 1.54 2.212v7.155h5.111v-7.652c0-3.793-1.513-5.69-4.541-5.69-1.638 0-2.846.63-3.623 1.888V5.366h-5.113v13.069h5.113zm15.383 0V11.28c0-1.475.504-2.212 1.514-2.212 1.025 0 1.538.737 1.538 2.212v7.155h5.113v-7.652c0-3.793-1.514-5.69-4.542-5.69-1.638 0-2.846.63-3.623 1.888V5.366h-5.113v13.069h5.113zM64.958 24l8.289-18.634H67.91l-2.532 6.684-2.258-6.684h-5.584l5.435 11.802L59.944 24h5.014zm13.67-5.292c1.638 0 2.995-.36 4.07-1.08 1.076-.721 1.614-1.769 1.614-3.144-.083-1.855-1.465-3.246-4.145-4.173l-1.44-.597c-.314-.1-.537-.198-.67-.298a.45.45 0 0 1-.198-.373c0-.414.273-.62.819-.62.678 0 1.183.347 1.514 1.043l3.698-1.044c-.894-2.22-2.614-3.329-5.162-3.329-1.522 0-2.788.398-3.797 1.193-1.01.795-1.514 1.83-1.514 3.105 0 .398.058.766.173 1.106.116.34.29.638.522.894.231.257.455.48.67.671.215.19.488.369.819.534.33.166.583.286.757.36.173.075.41.162.707.261l.422.15 1.489.546c.364.133.6.244.707.335a.449.449 0 0 1 .161.36c0 .431-.405.647-1.216.647-1.19 0-1.902-.53-2.134-1.59l-3.723.844c.464 2.8 2.416 4.2 5.857 4.2zm9.8-14.137c.91 0 1.613-.215 2.11-.646.495-.43.744-.977.744-1.64 0-.678-.24-1.23-.72-1.651C90.082.21 89.371 0 88.428 0c-.943 0-1.655.211-2.135.634-.48.422-.72.973-.72 1.652 0 .662.249 1.209.745 1.64.497.43 1.2.645 2.11.645zm2.556 13.864V5.366H85.87v13.069h5.113zm7.74.273c1.737 0 2.977-.63 3.722-1.888v1.615h5.112V.472h-5.112v6.534c-.745-1.275-1.985-1.913-3.723-1.913-1.753 0-3.214.642-4.38 1.926-1.166 1.283-1.75 2.91-1.75 4.882 0 1.97.584 3.598 1.75 4.882 1.166 1.283 2.627 1.925 4.38 1.925zm1.39-3.9c-.729 0-1.312-.274-1.75-.82-.439-.547-.658-1.243-.658-2.087 0-.845.215-1.54.645-2.087.447-.547 1.034-.82 1.762-.82s1.311.273 1.75.82c.438.546.657 1.242.657 2.087 0 .844-.219 1.54-.657 2.087-.439.546-1.022.82-1.75.82zm16.698 3.9c2.597 0 4.624-.754 6.08-2.26l-2.11-2.833c-1.042.845-2.217 1.267-3.524 1.267-.992 0-1.799-.224-2.42-.67-.62-.448-.93-.879-.93-1.293h9.604c.083-.298.124-.687.124-1.167 0-2.054-.674-3.677-2.022-4.87-1.349-1.193-3.073-1.789-5.175-1.789-2.25 0-4.028.671-5.335 2.013-1.307 1.341-1.961 2.956-1.961 4.844 0 1.938.69 3.549 2.072 4.833 1.382 1.283 3.247 1.925 5.597 1.925zm2.208-8.149h-5.112c.033-.613.298-1.08.794-1.404.496-.323 1.084-.484 1.762-.484.678 0 1.266.165 1.762.497a1.7 1.7 0 0 1 .794 1.391z" />
  </svg>
);

export default Logo;
```

The problem is that whenever I try to change the size of the SVG (className="w-32 h-44" for example), only the "container" size changes. The actual content size is static.

Comment: @Luuk I believe the linked SO answer uses `width/height` attributes while the OP is asking how to adjust the size with CSS classes. Still will be helpful for the OP so +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have [viewBox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/viewBox) to make the SVG scalable via classes.

From the devtools I saw the scale of your SVG as `124:24`.  So keep the same aspect ratio, I used, `viewBox="0 0 124 24"`, where first two zeros specify `x/y` coord in SVG space.

- **Runnable Demo**: https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-answer-on-svg-scaling-with-tailwind-css-qwdhzl?file=/src/App.js:24-3260
- **Tailwind Play**: https://play.tailwindcss.com/QAe9s28wfr

```js
const Logo = (props) => (
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 124 24" {...props}>
    <path d="M5.857 18.708c1.638 0 2.995-.36 4.07-1.08 1.075-.721 1.613-1.769 1.613-3.144-.083-1.855-1.464-3.246-4.144-4.173l-1.44-.597c-.314-.1-.538-.198-.67-.298a.45.45 0 0 1-.198-.373c0-.414.273-.62.819-.62.678 0 1.182.347 1.513 1.043l3.698-1.044c-.893-2.22-2.614-3.329-5.162-3.329-1.522 0-2.788.398-3.797 1.193C1.15 7.08.645 8.116.645 9.39c0 .398.058.766.174 1.106.116.34.29.638.521.894.232.257.455.48.67.671.215.19.488.369.82.534.33.166.582.286.756.36.174.075.41.162.707.261l.422.15 1.49.546c.363.133.6.244.707.335a.449.449 0 0 1 .16.36c0 .431-.404.647-1.215.647-1.191 0-1.903-.53-2.134-1.59L0 14.509c.463 2.8 2.416 4.2 5.857 4.2zm11.636 0c1.638 0 2.845-.63 3.623-1.888v1.615h5.112V5.366h-5.112v7.156c0 1.474-.505 2.21-1.514 2.21-1.026 0-1.539-.736-1.539-2.21V5.366h-5.112v7.653c0 3.793 1.514 5.69 4.542 5.69zm16.103-.273V11.28c0-1.475.504-2.212 1.513-2.212 1.026 0 1.54.737 1.54 2.212v7.155h5.111v-7.652c0-3.793-1.513-5.69-4.541-5.69-1.638 0-2.846.63-3.623 1.888V5.366h-5.113v13.069h5.113zm15.383 0V11.28c0-1.475.504-2.212 1.514-2.212 1.025 0 1.538.737 1.538 2.212v7.155h5.113v-7.652c0-3.793-1.514-5.69-4.542-5.69-1.638 0-2.846.63-3.623 1.888V5.366h-5.113v13.069h5.113zM64.958 24l8.289-18.634H67.91l-2.532 6.684-2.258-6.684h-5.584l5.435 11.802L59.944 24h5.014zm13.67-5.292c1.638 0 2.995-.36 4.07-1.08 1.076-.721 1.614-1.769 1.614-3.144-.083-1.855-1.465-3.246-4.145-4.173l-1.44-.597c-.314-.1-.537-.198-.67-.298a.45.45 0 0 1-.198-.373c0-.414.273-.62.819-.62.678 0 1.183.347 1.514 1.043l3.698-1.044c-.894-2.22-2.614-3.329-5.162-3.329-1.522 0-2.788.398-3.797 1.193-1.01.795-1.514 1.83-1.514 3.105 0 .398.058.766.173 1.106.116.34.29.638.522.894.231.257.455.48.67.671.215.19.488.369.819.534.33.166.583.286.757.36.173.075.41.162.707.261l.422.15 1.489.546c.364.133.6.244.707.335a.449.449 0 0 1 .161.36c0 .431-.405.647-1.216.647-1.19 0-1.902-.53-2.134-1.59l-3.723.844c.464 2.8 2.416 4.2 5.857 4.2zm9.8-14.137c.91 0 1.613-.215 2.11-.646.495-.43.744-.977.744-1.64 0-.678-.24-1.23-.72-1.651C90.082.21 89.371 0 88.428 0c-.943 0-1.655.211-2.135.634-.48.422-.72.973-.72 1.652 0 .662.249 1.209.745 1.64.497.43 1.2.645 2.11.645zm2.556 13.864V5.366H85.87v13.069h5.113zm7.74.273c1.737 0 2.977-.63 3.722-1.888v1.615h5.112V.472h-5.112v6.534c-.745-1.275-1.985-1.913-3.723-1.913-1.753 0-3.214.642-4.38 1.926-1.166 1.283-1.75 2.91-1.75 4.882 0 1.97.584 3.598 1.75 4.882 1.166 1.283 2.627 1.925 4.38 1.925zm1.39-3.9c-.729 0-1.312-.274-1.75-.82-.439-.547-.658-1.243-.658-2.087 0-.845.215-1.54.645-2.087.447-.547 1.034-.82 1.762-.82s1.311.273 1.75.82c.438.546.657 1.242.657 2.087 0 .844-.219 1.54-.657 2.087-.439.546-1.022.82-1.75.82zm16.698 3.9c2.597 0 4.624-.754 6.08-2.26l-2.11-2.833c-1.042.845-2.217 1.267-3.524 1.267-.992 0-1.799-.224-2.42-.67-.62-.448-.93-.879-.93-1.293h9.604c.083-.298.124-.687.124-1.167 0-2.054-.674-3.677-2.022-4.87-1.349-1.193-3.073-1.789-5.175-1.789-2.25 0-4.028.671-5.335 2.013-1.307 1.341-1.961 2.956-1.961 4.844 0 1.938.69 3.549 2.072 4.833 1.382 1.283 3.247 1.925 5.597 1.925zm2.208-8.149h-5.112c.033-.613.298-1.08.794-1.404.496-.323 1.084-.484 1.762-.484.678 0 1.266.165 1.762.497a1.7 1.7 0 0 1 .794 1.391z" />
  </svg>
);
```

[image: demo]

For more info on SVG scaling check out CSS Tricks article,
https://css-tricks.com/scale-svg/

Adam Wathan (creator of Tailwind CSS) also has a vid on working with SVG: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MbUyHQRq2go&list=PL7CcGwsqRpSM3w9BT_21tUU8JN2SnyckR&index=12

Comment: "From the devtools I saw the scale of your SVG as 124:24"

This made me realize I was scaling my SVG incorrectly. Thank you